# Can an IR thermometer be used to check wall insulation?

Tags: insulation, energy-efficiency

IR point thermometers have come down a lot in price. IR imaging cameras haven't.

Is there a reasonable approach to using the point thermometer to determine how well or poorly insulated my walls currently are, or should I spring for a "proper" evaluation? (Or try to get an imager at tolerable price through eBay?)

Yes, I know some folks have kluged frameworks with stepper motors to scan and area and build up an image out of individual points. If it came to that, I'd rather throw money at the problem.

(The last few times I had energy audits done, they said they'd check on this... and then didn't do so. Admittedly, having had the place air-sealed and the roof insulation deepened I'm already ahead of most of my neighbors, but I'm still willing to invest in improving it further if there's clear evidence that doing so would help.)

Comment: Your asking an opinion. This should be in chat,  which should be a good discussion.

Comment: I'm asking whether a recommended procedure exists and how to use a particular tool productively. If the answer is "no, and not for this purpose", that's fine. I don't think that's an opinion question. (At least not more than any other tool question is.) If anything, I'm seeking a way to get more facts so I can *AVOID* relying on opinion.

Answer (score 2):

the thermometer is only going to show the spot "point"ed at, this is better for spot checking.  The camera will show a section, better suited for larger areas. The thermometer method will only work so far as to how thorough you are when checking. The rest of the answer would be speculative opinion. There also comes a point when the savings don't out weigh the expenditure.

Comment: Valid point. On the other hand, there could have been recommendations for getting an initial best-guess -- "if you find more than a few points on the surface that are more than X degrees warmer than the outside air in midwinter, or if you find a difference of more than X degrees that seems to be stud versus cavity, your walls are basically uninsulated; if the difference is less than X they're well-enough insulated that you don't have to think about this." Or something like that. (1890 house; I have _no_ idea whether there's anything in the walls.) Probe camera might be better way to find out.

Comment: @keshlam for cheap inspection the IR point thermometer will work fine, but you'll be doing alot of scanning. The IR image camera, gets it done faster. The reason I didn't suggest a probe camera is that it won't be any good for R values, it'll just shows whether or not anything is there and what condition it is in.

Comment: Good point, though actually my first question is "Is there anything there at all?" I've been assuming so since my heating bill isn't outrageous, but...

Answer (score 1):

> IR point thermometers have come down a lot in price. IR imaging cameras haven't

Actually, they have. The FLIR One, at $350, and the Seek Thermal, at $200, have lowered the floor on IR camera pricing significantly.

Comment: Still almost an order of magnitude higher than the point versions, but definitely better than they were. On the other hand, folks have been (ab)using the fact that cell-phone cameras pick up some near-IR to generate false-color temp images from those; that may be the simplest and cheapest answer.

Comment: Near IR is not usable for thermal imaging at the temperatures involved in home inspection. It's not emitted in significant quantities until you start getting into the 1000°F range.